# change multiple image on hover in different tables

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to link images in one table to another(bigger) images in the other table

Basically I have 2 tables, left and right.
in the left table I have two small images.
in the right table I have nothing.
I want to be able to hover over small image in the left table and see the bigger corresponding image in the right table.

I figured how to swap two image in the same table with html/css, but can't figure out how to achieve the functionality that I've described above.

Any CSS or HTML advice would be great,

Thanks a lot,

anton

P.S. I am the beginner with CSS

Comment: Would you like a javascript solution?  I think that would be simple.

Comment: Impossible with CSS, easy with javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Well.. There is a simple way of doing this in javascript.  So javascript is simple.

Your html (this is obviously not yours but its a scenario)

```
<div class='right'>
    <div class='img'>
        <img id='1' src='img1-small.png'>
    </div>
    <div class='img'>
        <img id='2' src='img2-small.png'>
    </div>
    <div class='img'>
        <img id='3' src='img3-small.png'>
    </div>
</div>
<div class='left'>
    <div class='img ui-helper-hidden'>
        <img id='1' src='img1-large.png'>
    </div>
    <div class='img ui-helper-hidden'>
        <img id='2' src='img2-large.png'>
    </div>
    <div class='img ui-helper-hidden'>
        <img id='3' src='img3-large.png'>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now i am assuming you have jQuery (sorry if you do not, but the idea is similar).

```
$(function() {
        $('.right .img').hover(
        //over
        function() {
            var $this = $(this),
                id = $('img', $this).attr("id");

            $(".left #" + id).fadeIn(200);
        },
        //out
        function() {
            var $this = $(this),
                id = $('img', $this).attr("id");

            $(".left #" + id).fadeOut(200);
        }
    )
});
```

Comment: do i have to create custom file for "you have jQuery" in dremaviewer? I have the latest version but I do not see the option for that, I see javascript though. Thank you,

Comment: You can import jQuery into your project with this line.  `<script type="text/javascript"src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.js"></script>`

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Michael's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/499419/michael) post

```
<div class='imgcontainer'>

        <img src='img1-small.png' class='swapme'>

        <img src='img2-small.png' class='swapme'>

        <img src='img3-small.png' class='swapme'>

</div>
<div id='image_here'>

</div>

<!--delete the next line if you've already included jquery  -->
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js'
           type="text/javascript"></script>
<script> 
   //this runs when the document is ready, if you're new to jquery, just ignore this and take it for granted 
$(document).ready(function(){ 
   $(".swapme").hover(
     function(){ //on mouse over
        var newSrc = $(this).attr("src");
        newSrc= newSrc.replace('/small/','large'); 
        // this assumes that files are named like so
        // small file : img3-small.png 
        // large file : img3-large.png
        $("#image_here").html("<img src='" + newSrc + "' id='deleteMe'/>")
     },//end mouse over
     function(){//on mouse out
        $("#deleteMe").remove(); // show image only on mouse over
     }//end mouse out
)//end hover
})//end document.ready

</script>
```

And yes, this depends on jQuery too, but i think it's the easiest to understand and code way to do it

Answer (score 0):

Try this,Here I have a big image on the left and 3 images right.

On mouse hover sll 3 images they will replace big one. on mouse out old image will come back

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title><br />

</head>

<body>
<p>
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function changeImage(img){
   document.getElementById('bigImage').src=img;

}
</script>


<table width="45%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="float:left;">
  <tr>
    <th height="380" scope="col"><img src="../Pictures/Bigcircle.png" alt="" width="284" height="156" id="bigImage" /></th>
  </tr>
</table>
<table width="45%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="float:left;">
  <tr>
    <th scope="col"><div>
      <p> <img src="../Pictures/lightcircle1.png" height="79" width="78" onmouseover="changeImage('../Pictures/lightcircle2.png')" onmouseout="changeImage('../Pictures/Bigcircle.png')"/> </p>
      <p><img src="../Pictures/lightcircle2.png" alt="" width="120" height="100" onmouseover="changeImage('../Pictures/lightcircle.png')" onmouseout="changeImage('../Pictures/Bigcircle.png')"/></p>
      <p><img src="../Pictures/lightcircle3.png" alt="" width="78" height="79" onmouseover="changeImage('../Pictures/lightcircle2.png')" onmouseout="changeImage('../Pictures/Bigcircle.png')"/></p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      </br>
    </div></th>
  </tr>
</table>
<p>&nbsp; </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Now only 1 image is being changed, insted of that you can change multiple images. You just have to add their codes in javascript