# Two images change places when hover CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm looking for an answer to my problem. I have one large image on the top and eight small images on the bottom of my page. I want to make it so when you hover the small image (it's also a link which goes to different place) the large image changes to this small image. So clearly explained, two images change/swap places. And when I unhover the large image changes back.

Here's the picture so you know what I'm talking about!
And I'm looking for CSS, React (if there is any useful components) or just JavaScript-solution (if else statement or something like that).

https://i.ibb.co/C5m5sH3/demonstration.png

Thank you for your time!

Comment: This question is a duplicate of a few other posts, including: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8996900/change-multiple-image-on-hover-in-different-tables

See if this solves your issue

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery for your case, capture the **hover** event and update main image source.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.thumbnail').hover(function(e){
    src = $(e.target).data('main');
    $("#target_img").attr('src', src);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main_image" style="width: 200px; height: 100px">
  <img id="target_img" src="#"/>
</div>

<ul>
  <li>
    <img class="thumbnail" src="https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.wx64GmJDu2nd32eO_tieDgHaEK?pid=Api&rs=1" data-main="https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.wx64GmJDu2nd32eO_tieDgHaEK?pid=Api&rs=1" width="50px" height="50px"/>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img class="thumbnail" src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/_138avbqsoJQ/S31zZz9qPZI/AAAAAAAABNQ/ARDHrOa5_pg/s400/Loch_Lomond.JPG" data-main="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/_138avbqsoJQ/S31zZz9qPZI/AAAAAAAABNQ/ARDHrOa5_pg/s400/Loch_Lomond.JPG" width="50px" height="50px"/>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `mouseover` and `mouseout` event listeners to change the background image of your big div.

The below snippet explains it all -

```js
function change(e){
  document.getElementById("main").style.backgroundImage = `url(${e.target.src})`; 
}

let imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("img");

for(let i = 0; i<imgs.length; i++){
  imgs[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
    change(event);
  });
  imgs[i].addEventListener("mouseout", function(){
    document.getElementById("main").style.backgroundImage = `url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/11/28/11/03/advent-5784271__340.jpg")`;
  });
}
```

```css
#main{ 
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  border: 3px dashed red;
  background-image: url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/11/28/11/03/advent-5784271__340.jpg");
  }

img{
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main"></div>

<img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/03/24/11/21/winter-4963715__340.jpg">
<img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/12/10/19/15/new-years-eve-4686590__340.jpg">
<img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/11/17/15/44/cup-5752775__340.jpg">
<img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/05/18/13/34/branches-4211837__340.jpg">
```

Currently I don't know what is the structure of your html, but you can tweak this solution to fit your case.

Answer (score 0):

I have created an example of the swap effect that you specified, and created a code pen of it using colors instead:

https://codepen.io/DaudWaqas/pen/xxEgxLm

```
<section class="main" id="main" style="background-color: #000"></section>
<div>
  <Section style="background-color: orange" onmouseover="grabAndSwap(event)"></section>
  <Section style="background-color: cyan" onmouseover="grabAndSwap(event)"></section>
  <Section style="background-color: maroon" onmouseover="grabAndSwap(event)"></section>
  <Section style="background-color: #444" onmouseover="grabAndSwap(event)"></section>
</div>
<div>
  <Section style="background-color: #ff0000" onmouseover="grabAndSwap(event)"></section>
  <Section style="background-color: #00ff00" onmouseover="grabAndSwap(event)"></section>
  <Section style="background-color: #0000ff" onmouseover="grabAndSwap(event)"></section>
  <Section style="background-color: magenta" onmouseover="grabAndSwap(event)"></section>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.main {
  height: 30vh;
  width: 100%;
}
section {
  height: 15vh;
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
}
div {
  height: 15vh;
  width: 100%;
}
```

JS:

```
const main = document.getElementById('main');
function grabAndSwap(event) {
  var toSwapWith = event.target;
  var mainColor = main.style.backgroundColor;
    console.log(mainColor);
  var otherColor = toSwapWith.style.backgroundColor;
    console.log(otherColor);
  
 main.style.backgroundColor = otherColor;
 toSwapWith.style.backgroundColor = mainColor;
}
```

Comment: Hi I edited my post so that you can better understand what I mean! Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

You can capture mouseover in Javascript and simply swap the background-image and swap back on mouseout.

```js
  const picEls= document.getElementsByClassName('small');
  const largeEl = document.getElementsByClassName('large')[0];
  for (let i=0; i<picEls.length; i++) {
    picEls[i].addEventListener('mouseover', hovered);
    picEls[i].addEventListener('mouseout', hovered);
  }

  function hovered(event) {
    const bg = event.target.style.backgroundImage;
    this.style.backgroundImage = largeEl.style.backgroundImage;
    largeEl.style.backgroundImage = bg;
  }
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.pic {
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-size: cover;
}
.large {
  width: 40vw;
  height: 30vw;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;  
}
.small {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20vw;
  height: 15vw;
  margin: 2vw;  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="large pic" style="background-image: linear-gradient(red,yellow);"></div>
  <div class="small pic" style="background-image: linear-gradient(red,green);"></div>
  <div class="small pic" style="background-image: linear-gradient(green,blue);"></div>
  <div class="small pic" style="background-image: linear-gradient(blue,red);"></div>
  <div class="small pic" style="background-image: linear-gradient(cyan,yellow);"></div>
  <div class="small pic" style="background-image: linear-gradient(yellow,magenta);"></div>
  <div class="small pic" style="background-image: linear-gradient(magenta,cyan);"></div>
  <div class="small pic" style="background-image: linear-gradient(cyan,red);"></div>
  <div class="small pic" style="background-image: linear-gradient(yellow, green);"></div>
</div>
```